# How do you make a WebView work?

Tags: java, android

[image: This this how the layout looks]

And this is how the Java code looks:

```
package com.example.admin.testingwebview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void go(View view){
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
}
}
```

The layout XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.testingwebview.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="go" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried it on an emulator as well as real device.
The EditText and Button part are A-OK, But the Web View shows nothing . . . .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you run it on a device/emulator ?

Comment: what is the string that comes from `editText.getText().toString()`?

Comment: And what is the problem? Crash? Blank page? Page with nonsense?

Comment: Please post the XML file code too.

Comment: Did you add INTERNET permission to the manifest?

Comment: No. The button go is wired to call the method 'go'.

Comment: INTERNET permission is in the manifest file.

Comment: The link is in the form "www.example.com" or "h.t.t.p://www.example.com" ? in the second i use the dot or the example become a link it's http

Comment: Its just that Web View remains blank.

Comment: The link i tried is in the form of www.example.com. Why is that?

Comment: BINGO! It was the link's problem . . . . .

Comment: http:// . . . . . worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
EditText data = (EditText) findViewbyId(R.id.edittext);

String result = data.getText().toString(); //Take URL from edittext

if (!result.startsWith("http://") && !result.startsWith("https://"))
      result = "http://" + result;
```

If you don't set the http after the link string nothing is shown in the webview, same for intent that start the BrowserWeb

Comment: Helped a lot . . . .

Comment: No problem i had the same problem, i suggest that don't use the web view it's better an intent that start the Browser of the device!
Next time make a little search to this site you can find your solution without open a new question!
Enjoy! ;)